# Customizing the Code Analysis Messages in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, customization, code-analysis

Is it possible to modify the messages for the existing rules in Visual Studio 2012's Code Analysis? If so, how can this be done?

I have seen that you can [create your own custom rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380660.aspx), but I would like to modify the existing rules that it provides.

Answer (score 0):

No this cannot be done. The text is embedded in the rule's assembly resources. I've, in the past, managed to create a custom rule that wraps (loads using reflection, executes and intercepts the results) an existing rule and from there it's possible go through the outcomes of the wrapped rule and return your own set of results based on that.

Comment: I had originally asked for  this with regards to VS 2012. Are there any versions that have or are slated to have this feature?

Comment: No. And with the introduction of Roslyn the old binary Code Analysis features are going to be phased out in the near future.